# TabContainer not visible under firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

I am using Ajax tab control in my aspx page. On IE and Chrome it works fine. However it is not working under Firefox.

It's `visibility` is `hidden`. I tried various options setting `visibility` to `visible` from CSS class, set `ActiveTabIndex` value from code behind.
Still it is not working.

I am using `ToolkitScriptManager` instead of `ScriptManager`.

Please suggest any workaround.

Answer (score 1):

give a try with firebug to trace...some style might hiding your tab..may be inherited from another control

Comment: It's display is set to hidden automatically. Not sure how.